# Sqlite create/insert number sequence into existing column based on current number order

Tags: python, sqlite, sql-update, row-number

I'm using Python with SQLite and would like to insert a number sequence (1, 2, 3, 4...) into a single SELECTION_POSITION column in the SELECTION_GROUPS table.  I tried to use row_number but am unsure how/if I can do an update with that rather than just a select:

```
cursor.execute('select SELECTION_POSITION, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY SELECTION_POSITION) AS row_number FROM SELECTION_GROUPS ORDER BY SELECTION_POSITION;')
```

If this cannot be done, is there another/better way to overwrite/insert values into this column based on that columns current order (trying to have it autocorrect itself if the program has found any duplicate/out of order entries and to keep it in as similar position order as possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your version of SQLite is 3.33.0+ you can use the `UPDATE...FROM` syntax to update the table:

```
UPDATE SELECTION_GROUPS AS t1
SET SELECTION_POSITION = t2.rn
FROM (
  SELECT rowid, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SELECTION_POSITION, rowid) AS rn
  FROM SELECTION_GROUPS
) AS t2
WHERE t2.rowid = t1.rowid;
```

Comment: This works fairly well, except in the occurrence of a duplicate number(s).  I am unsure how one would resolve that particular issue

Comment: @Zeloz what result do you want in case of duplicate SELECTION_POSITION?

Comment: basically to overwrite the next number in the row.  (1, 2, 3, 4, 5...) and so on.  Basically trying to get it so that if anytime a value is incorrectly put in, say a duplicate 5, all the rest of the rows will "shift" to try and accommodate that inserted value

Comment: @Zeloz my 1st query with ROW_NUMBER() window function will work for this case too. Is your version of SQLite 3.33.0+?

Comment: I believe the version I'm running is 3.36.0 but am still getting the duplicate values

Comment: If you run the same code but insert another (5) on the same sql query you had earlier, the output includes two 4's for instance.  (looks like the position of the insert affects the result, I put the (5) at the end)

Comment: @Zeloz check my edited answer.

Comment: That worked great!  Thank you very much